# jQuery drop file to upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna upload file with drop file 
and i know it's impossible with $.ajax 
Here 
This my code

```
$('.eCover').on(
    'dragover',
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
)
$('.eCover').on(
    'dragenter',
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
)
$('.eCover').on(
    'drop',
    function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
            if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                /*UPLOAD FILES HERE*/
                upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
            }   
        }
    }
);
function upload(files){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: {data:files},
        dataType: "json",
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

i cant send data file with ajax, what should i do ? 
i want try it by code not wit plugin
Thank you

Comment: Maybe usefull for you: https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` object to upload using `FormData`

```
function upload(myfile) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", myfile);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
        xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Taken from [this tutorial](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/)